# Hardware requirements for ALM server : Jenkins + Nexus + SVN + Maven + Ant + Sonar

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, nexus, alm

I'm installing and ALM server  on Linux Ubuntu using some tools :

- Jenkins
- Nexus
- MAVEN
- Sonar
- SVN
- ANT

I deployed Nexus and Jenkins in the same Tomcat Server (/Webapps ).

I'm using VM Virtual box with Ubuntu ( 6 CPU , 4GO of Memory)

The question is : What is the hardware requirements to let the server run without overloading CPU and Memory overflow ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that depends strongly on the number of projects you plan to host on that infrastructure. Jenkins usually runs fine with 2-3gb, nexus with 512mb, sonar around 1-1.5gb. Running SVN and Apache using HTTP as protocol requires around 150mb per Apache process - so the number of concurrent svn users would give a hint on this. maven itself runs inside jenkins, so the diskspace is more of an issue here. I would calculate several gigabytes for that in advance - but again it depends on how many projects are build and what these contain.

Answer (score 0):

you need memory mainly for Jenkins and Sonar. The CPU is necessary to run the Jenkins jobs. So, your hardware requirements depends on number of jobs. We have a similar Virtual Appliance with Jenkins, Sonar, Nexus, Redmine, SVN/Git and a SSO, and running fine with 4GB and 2 CPUs.

Comment: @manuel-jesus-recena-sotoDid :  you install Jenkins and Sonar in the same Tomcat instance?I've go an exception **Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"**

Comment: Yes, we have Sonar, Nexus, Jenkins and Redmine in the same Apache Tomcat instance. Also an SSO.